# How can I start a UWP application from code without App.xaml file using Main() method?

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

Normally when you create a new Universal Windows application, Visual Studio generates an App.xaml file, which I assume will in the background generate the application start method of Main(string args).

I need to start my application without a Xaml file by manually writing the Main() method.

In WPF I could write the following:

```
 [STAThread()]
 public static void Main() => new MyAppClass().Run();
```

But in UWP there is no **Run()** method in **Windows.UI.Xaml.Application** class. So the above doesn't work.

What code should I write instead to launch the application (assuming my application class is named MyApplication which inherits from Windows.UI.Xaml.Application)?

Comment: What's your use case for having this requirement? Maybe there are better ways to approach it.

Comment: The problem is that I need my application class to inherit from another class which inherits from Windows.UI.Xaml.Application. Xaml cannot handle that. I didn't include that in the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: That is possible and is exactly what we do with Prism, having [another class for each IoC container](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Windows/blob/master/SplitViewSample/SplitViewSample/App.xaml.cs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it!

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Start((p) => new MyApplication());
 }
```